# how to assign multiple values to an attribute through text field in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to create an attribute in Magento CE, in such a way that I can assign multiple values to it through text field. I know multiple values can also be assigned using multiple select or drop-down input type. But values that can be assigned to our attribute run into thousands so multiple select is not practical. Is there any way through which I can assign values through a text field which are then stored in a list or array which can be  manipulated individually.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without gaining more information about the specifics of what you want to do, here's a few options:

1. Just comma-delimit your entries in the text box. The exact value will be stored for the attribute in the DB. Code that uses this attribute at some point can do an `$var = explode(',' $this->getAttributeName())` call on it to get a non-associative array of the values
2. If you want to allow the selection of numerous possible values and place those into a serialized string for storage, use something like http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ but make the text-box hidden and supply the option tags in the form - edit the jQuery from that library to insert the tag name into the hidden text box on-click and change the color of the tag on the frontend so the user knows its been selected. At the form submit, your POST data just contains a comma-delimited string of those tag names. The same jQuery library can be slightly altered to render the chosen tags as being selected by parsing out the pre-stored attribute text using an explode().